# Extract integer from HTML file with BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the integer (0) from within the div of the class 'high' in beautifulsoup to store in a variable:

```
[<tr class="high">
<td>
<div>
<a href="#*_high">High</a>
</div>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<div>0</div>
</td>
</tr>]
```

I am able to extract the section above from the html file using

```
high = soup.find_all(class_="high")
```

However any attempts to filter down to just the integer result in empty results:

```
div = soup.find("div", class_= "High")
print(div)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue and get a picture. How to create [mcve] - Providing some code that shows some of your effort, would also be nice Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First locate the `<tr class='high'>` tag. From there locate both of the `<td>` elements. The second one contains the data you want. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<tr class="high">
<td>
<div>
<a href="#*_high">High</a>
</div>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<div>0</div>
</td>
</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
tr = soup.find('tr', class_="high")
data = int(tr.find_all('td')[1].get_text(strip=True))

print(data)
```